# Jboss war deployment exception

Tags: inputstream, jboss7.x, ioexception

I'm using Jboss7.1 final.And while deploying war I'm getting exception as follows

> 08:07:13,065 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (HttpManagementService-threads - 1) JBAS015891: Caught exception
>   closing input stream for uploaded deployment content:
>   java.io.IOException: Stream closed    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
>   ..

I'm unable to find where is error..

Comment: It's really tough to read this output. I'm not sure what kind of format is being used for the log output, but I see no new lines. Could you add a stacktrace with better formatting?

Comment: Bug is reolved.It was generating due to network issues with remote system.Thanks.